# Remove an element from array of object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Basically I want to group the object which has same value of key.

```
const dupObj = [
  {
    "uuid": "",
    "quantity": 0,
    "distributeStoreUuid": "",
    "distributeStore__acceptanceTaskDetailsUuid": "",
    "acceptanceTaskUuid": "acabb997-fc06-47ba-ae29-d7aea9a6a022",
  },
  {
    "uuid": "",
    "quantity": 3,
    "acceptanceTaskUuid": "acabb997-fc06-47ba-ae29-d7aea9a6a022",
  }
 ]
```

and here is the expected result

```
[
 {
   "uuid": "",
   "quantity": 3,
   "distributeStoreUuid": "",
   "distributeStore__acceptanceTaskDetailsUuid": "",
   "acceptanceTaskUuid": "acabb997-fc06-47ba-ae29-d7aea9a6a022",
 }
]
```

I'm experimenting with ES6 Set and here what I have so far

```
const uniKeys = [...(new Set(dupObj.map(({ acceptanceTaskUuid }) => acceptanceTaskUuid)))];
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance

Comment: same value of key is which column?acceptanceTaskUuid or uuid or distributeStoreUuid or acceptanceTaskUuid?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention key. It's `acceptanceTaskUuid`

Comment: What is the logic when you have the same property but different values for the same object (`quantity` in your example)?

Comment: it will store the latter. The earlier quantity discarded

Comment: Please provide a bit more extensive input (with maybe 4, 5 entries) and desired output for it.

Comment: You could use a Map (or plain JS object) with the key being your id and value the object and then use [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to merge duplicate objects together.

Comment: @xanderhow do merge using map and return new by Object.assign()? Not really sure how I go about it

Comment: See my answer below for a working example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should work:

```js
const dedupe = originalArray => originalArray.reduce((array, obj) => {
  const index = array.findIndex(item => item.acceptanceTaskUuid === obj.acceptanceTaskUuid)
    
  // if there already is no other acceptance task uuid
  // then append the obj to the array else add the quantities together
  return index === -1 ? [...array, obj] : Object.assign([], array, {
    [index]: Object.assign({}, array[index], obj)
  })
}, [])

console.log(dedupe([
  {
    "uuid": "",
    "quantity": 0,
    "distributeStoreUuid": "",
    "distributeStore__acceptanceTaskDetailsUuid": "",
    "acceptanceTaskUuid": "acabb997-fc06-47ba-ae29-d7aea9a6a022",
  },
  {
    "uuid": "",
    "quantity": 3,
    "acceptanceTaskUuid": "acabb997-fc06-47ba-ae29-d7aea9a6a022",
  },
  {
    "uuid": "",
    "quantity": 4,
    "acceptanceTaskUuid": "foobar"
  },
  {
    "uuid": "",
    "quantity": 13,
    "acceptanceTaskUuid": "foobarbaz",
  },
  {
    "uuid": "",
    "quantity": 6,
    "acceptanceTaskUuid": "foobar",
  },
]))
```

The `findIndex` function returns the index of the first item in the array which matches the condition. Basically the code above starts with an empty array, loops over the original array (`reduce`) and finds the index of the item with the same acceptance task uuid as the current object each iteration. If there is a duplicate then it adds the quantities together, else it just appends the new item to the array

**EDIT**: Made Immutable

Comment: would love to see it in ES6 style

Comment: Ok used arrow functions

Answer (score 1):

You can [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) the array into a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). On a each pass, get the object with the same `acceptanceTaskUuid` from the Map, or use an empty object, assign this to `current`. Use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate the array's object (`o`) entries, and check if the property is a number in `current`, and add it, or assign it if not. Then [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) the Map values to get an array:

```js
const dupObj = [{"uuid":"","quantity":1,"distributeStoreUuid":"","distributeStore__acceptanceTaskDetailsUuid":"","acceptanceTaskUuid":"acabb997-fc06-47ba-ae29-d7aea9a6a022"},{"uuid":"","quantity":3,"acceptanceTaskUuid":"acabb997-fc06-47ba-ae29-d7aea9a6a022"}]

const uniques = [...dupObj.reduce((m, o) => {
  const current = m.get(o.acceptanceTaskUuid) || {}

  Object.entries(o).forEach(([key, value]) => 
    current[key] = typeof current[key] === 'number' ? current[key] + value : value)

  return m.set(o.acceptanceTaskUuid, current)
}, new Map()).values()]

console.log(uniques)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` and store object on the `acceptanceTaskUuid` key,  if a duplicate object appears, merge them using `Object.assign`. Then extract the values using `Object.values()`.

```js
const dupObj = [ { "uuid": "", "quantity": 0, "distributeStoreUuid": "", "distributeStore__acceptanceTaskDetailsUuid": "", "acceptanceTaskUuid": "acabb997-fc06-47ba-ae29-d7aea9a6a022", }, { "uuid": "", "quantity": 3, "acceptanceTaskUuid": "acabb997-fc06-47ba-ae29-d7aea9a6a022"} ],
      result = Object.values(dupObj.reduce((r, o) => {
        r[o.acceptanceTaskUuid] = Object.assign(r[o.acceptanceTaskUuid] || {}, o);
        return r;
      }, {}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: and arrow function should not return assignment. That is what Eslint validate.

Comment: Updated the solution to merge the values.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Map (or plain JS object) with the key being your id and value the object and then use [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to merge duplicate objects together.

This is a simple loop algorithm without any fancy reduce or mapping operation, it should be simple to understand.

```
let map = new Map();
for (let obj of dupObj) {
    if (map.has(obj.acceptanceTaskUuid))
        map.set(obj.acceptanceTaskUuid, Object.assign(map.get(obj.acceptanceTaskUuid), obj)); // merge
    else
        map.set(obj.acceptanceTaskUuid, obj);
}

// map.values() return an iterator, not an array
for (let obj of map.values()) {
    console.log(obj);
}
```

Comment: @GuyWhoKnowsStuff It's not adding it takes the latest values as OP explained it? His comment was "it will store the latter. The earlier quantity discarded".

Answer (score -2):

Why not using lodash, so easy, so simple.

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#filter

Comment: I want to avoid extra loaded library.

Comment: Well, OK, 
(But you didn't mentioned that..  :-) )